# How to read from file and supply it to variables

Tags: vb.net, config

I am making a game engine. I need to load a text file into my program and then sort each line into a specific value.
I need to extract each line into specific string so I can read it in the program later.

This is how the config file looks:

```
title=HelloWorld
developer=MightyOnes
config=classic
```

And the code would extract `title=` into a string that says `HelloWorld`.
Same for the rest. Developer would be `MightyOnes`. I think you got it by now.

Comment: what you mean by special config file

Comment: It is a text file basically with a list of values.

Comment: what will be the content of the file? does it varying? how it looks like?

Comment: There is a preset amount of values you need to fill. It looks like above. I am counting 20-30 different values you can choose between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really need is a `Dictionary`. A dictionary can hold key-value pairs, which can later be retrieved by key name.

```
Dim KeyValues As Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '' to fill the dictionary
    KeyValues = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim fileContents = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Test\test.txt")  '-- replace with your config file name
    For Each line In fileContents
        Dim kv = Split(line, "=", 2)
        KeyValues.Add(kv(0), kv(1))
    Next

    '' to get a particular value from dictionary, say get value of "developer"
    Dim value As String = KeyValues("developer")
    MessageBox.Show(value)

End Sub
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Thank you.