# read specific values from text file

Tags: vb.net, file, text, streamreader

I have the following visual basic code, which is part of a custom class. I want a simple and effective way(use little computer resources) to assign the "value1" value(100) to "_field1","value2" value(8) to "_field2" etc. Any nice ideas? thanks

```
Private Sub readcrnFile()
    'read files and assing values to the properties
    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(_fileName)

    _field1 = sr.ReadToEnd()
    _field2 = sr.ReadToEnd()
    _field3 = sr.ReadToEnd()

    sr.Close()

End Sub
```

where _fileName is a full path to a text file which looks like this:

> value1: 100
>
> value2: 8
>
> value3: 80

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest reading up what the method ReadToEnd() does. it does not do what you are expecting....

Comment: Are there only three lines in this file? If that is the case, why should you care about computer resources?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a `Dictionary` object. Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32165877/1252228

Comment: @ZevSpitz three lines are an example, this could have been be thousands

Comment: But your code has only three fields. What do you expect to happen when there are more than three lines?

Comment: @ZevSpitz you are right, in this example it's only three. But I am curious in a more general approach, which potentially encounters numerous   fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `_field1`, `_field2` and `_field3` variables to a `List(Of String)` (i.e. named `field`) and access to each field using its index (`field(0)`, `field(1)`, `field(2)`).

```
Dim field As New List(Of String)

Private Sub readcrnFile()
    For Each line In File.ReadAllLines(_filename)
        For i = 1 To 3
            If line.Contains("value" & i) Then
                field.Add(line.Substring(line.IndexOf(":") + 2))
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `ReadAllLines` is not a good idea if the file is very large, as it loads the entire file into memory. Then again, it appears the OP's file has only three lines in it.

Comment: I know, but I did it because the OP's file has only three lines. But I've posted a better answer.

Comment: Do you suspect that the file will change between calls to `GetValue`? Otherwise, I suggest you delete your entire first approach, as there is no benefit in reading the entire file with each call to `GetValue`.

Comment: @ZevSpitz I've edited one of my old functions for ini files. And for these functions, I was suspecting that the file change between calls.

Comment: Why do you need the inner `For` loop? Is there a reason to suspect that the values will not be in order? You could simply do `field.Add(line.Substring...`

Comment: @ZevSpitz Because he has multiple values to verify if exists in the file (value1, value2). But imagine if there was more than 3 possible values. So I do a for loop from 1 to the number of possible values and check if the corresponding value exists. If yes, then I add the value to the list. He wants to *read specific values from text file*. But I think these values  can not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I will try them later and come back with my final result

Comment: @Spymag Don't forget to upvote and select as best answer if it works and helps you !

Comment: So i selected the sub with the list. I like the idea of storing my values into a list which I can manipulate later and it looks simpler than the dictionary. Thanks all for your contribution!

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub readcrnFile()
    Dim lines = File.ReadLines(_fileName)
    For Each line In lines
        Dim val = line.Split(":")(1).Trim
        'do something with val?
    Next
End Sub
```

Returning a dictionary is trivial:

```
Private Sub readcrnFile()
    Dim dict = File.ReadLines(_fileName).Select(Function(line) line.Split(":")).ToDictionary(Function(parts) parts(0).Trim, Function(parts) parts(1).Trim)
    Debug.WriteLine(dict("value1")) 'will print 100
End Sub
```